# Multiple buttons to navigate pages (activities) not working

Tags: android

I am trying to create an app where I have several activities. Activity 1 in the main page and has a button that will open activity2. Activity 2 has 2 buttons. 1 that goes back at act1 and the other opens activity 3.

Activity 1 works fine, it opens activity2. The button on activity 2 that goes back to act 1 works fine but the second to take me to activity 3 doesn't work. In the attached code the second OnClickListener is greyed out with a message that says " Method 'OnClickListener' is never used.

```
package com.example.android.buttons;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
```

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    private static Button button_sbm;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        OnClickButtonListener();


    }


    public void OnClickButtonListener() {

        button_sbm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button_sbm.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intentMainActivity = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intentMainActivity);
                    }



                    public void OnClickButtonListener() {
                        button_sbm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
                        button_sbm.setOnClickListener(
                                new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        Intent intentMain3Activity = new   Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
                                        startActivity(intentMain3Activity);
                                    }
                                }
                        );

                    }

                }
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: Try to start everything in onCreate, then work on making methods.  1) You put the Activity3 click listener inside the Activity2 listener 2) You can't have methods with the same name, if you had implemented it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your  `onClick` listener like this

```
  public void OnClickButtonListener() {
        button_sbm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button_sbm.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intentMainActivity = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intentMainActivity);
                    }
                }
        );
        button_sbm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button_sbm.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intentMain3Activity = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intentMain3Activity);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry to be a little thick, I don't understand what you mean here. Your reply looks the same as my original code??!

Comment: Ahh OK, you edited the postion. I didnt understand from your orignal post.

Comment: it dose't you have put clicked listener for third activity to launch in second back clicked listener

Comment: so for you for registering itself for listener to launch third activity you have to press back button for activity first

Answer (score 0):

**Try this -**

```
package com.example.android.buttons;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static Button button_sbm1 , button_sbm2;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
            button_sbm1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
           button_sbm2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

               button_sbm1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intentMainActivity = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intentMainActivity);
                    }

        });


                   button_sbm2.setOnClickListener(
                                new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        Intent intentMain3Activity = new   Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
                                        startActivity(intentMain3Activity);
                                    }
                                }
                        );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

implement your Activity from View.OnClickListener like

```
YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button btn1,btn2;
```

In OnCreate method

```
Button btn1=(Button)findViewById(yourbuttonid);
Button btn2=(Button)findViewById(yoursecondbtn);
btn1.setOnClickListener(this)
btn2.setOnClickListener(this)
```

after closing the onCreateMethod

```
@override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId){
case R.id.yourfirstButton:
Intent intentMainActivity = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,     MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intentMainActivity);
breal;
case R.id.secondbutton:
 Intent intentMainActivity = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,     MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intentMainActivity);
break;
}
```